# Kotlin - How to create a class member function similar to TextView.setText(String) that can be invoked as TextView.text = ""

Tags: android, kotlin

What i am trying to create is a Custom AlertDialogBox for which i would like to invoke the "setTitle()" method as `alertObject.title = "SomeTitle"`. My current AlertDialog code is as below

```
class AlertBox(context: Context) : BaseDialogHelper() {

override val dialogView: View by lazy {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null)
}

override val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context).setView(dialogView)

val txt_title: TextView by lazy {
    dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_title)
}

val txt_message: TextView by lazy {
    dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_message)
}

val btn_ok: Button by lazy {
    dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_done)
}

val btn_cancel: Button by lazy {
    dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_cancel)
}

//These are the methods that i want to change
fun setTitle(title: String) {
    txt_title.text = title
}

fun setMessage(message: String) {
    txt_message.text = message
}


fun onOkButtonClickListener(func: (() -> Unit)? = null) = with(btn_ok) {
    setClickListenerToButton(func)
}

fun onCancelButtonClickListener(func: (() -> Unit)? = null) = with(btn_cancel) {
    setClickListenerToButton(func)
}


private fun View.setClickListenerToButton(func: (() -> Unit)?) = setOnClickListener {
    func?.invoke()
    dialog?.dismiss()
}


}
```

I would like create a class member function similar to TextView.setText(String) that can be invoked as TextView.text = "". Can this be done for custom classes...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a property:

```
var text: String
    get() = txt_title.text
    set(value) { txt_title.text = value }
```